# Dynamic filename in Oracle SOA BPEL with %SEQ% value

Tags: bpel, oracle-soa, soa-suite

I'm developing an Oracle SOA composite with a BPEL process, which generates a file to fileserver using the standard file adapter.

I know 2 ways on how to assign the filename for the generated file:

1. In the adapter .jca -> `<property name="FileNamingConvention" value="test_%yyMMddHHmmss%_%SEQ%.edi"/>`
2. Pass a dynamic (or static) variable from the BPEL process using the invoke operation properties.

The question is can I somehow combine both, because of the **%SEQ%** value generated by the file adapter? Meaning I would want to achieve a concatenated value like:

```
(dynamicValueFromBPELprocess)_%yyMMddHHmmss%_%SEQ%.edi
```

Is this possible? Can I somehow get the next %SEQ% value the fileadapter would use, since, as far as I know, this is stored in some control directory for each composite.